# Subtraction is valid in big O-notation?

Tags: big-o, inequality

If we have `f(n)=O(g(n))` and `h(n)=O(x(n))`, then is it true that `f(n)-h(n)=O(g(n)-x(n))`?

I do not think so, because the inequality in the definition of O notation gets reversed while subtracting `x(n)` from `g(n)` , that is; since `f(n)<=c_1g(n)` for some constant `c_1` and `h(n)<=c_2x(n)` for another constant `c_2`, it is not clear whether we can directly subtract the terms. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. `f(n)` being `O(g(n))` and `h(n)` being `O(x(n))` does not imply `f(n)-h(n)` being `O(g(n)-x(n))`.

For a counter example just take `g(n) = x(n) = 1` and `f(n) = 2` and `h(n) = 1`. This clearly satisfies the assumptions, but `f(n)-h(n) = 1`, while `g(n)-x(n) = 0` and so the claim doesn't hold.

The only thing you can say about the difference is that it is `O(max(|h(n)|, |x(n)|))`.

Note however, that the same is true for addition if you allow negative values on the functions. In programming-related contexts it is generally assumed that the function only takes positive values and in that case subtraction only makes partially sense.